# Latex: installing texlive-publishers

Tags: software-installation, latex, texlive

I am trying to install the `texlive-publishers` latex package through `tlmgr`. After googling around and fixing some errors I've gotten as far as this one:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet
package texlive-publishers not present in package repository.
```

when I try to use

```
sudo tlmgr install texlive-publishers
```

And here I can't get any further. I also tried installing it manually with no luck (and I'd rather do it the normal way anyway).

Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried something new:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers
```

And seems to work; however I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  preview-latex-style texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-publishers-    doc
Suggested packages:
   python-pygments libfile-which-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  preview-latex-style texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-extra-doc texlive-publishers     texlive-publishers-doc
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 416 MB of archives.
After this operation, 619 MB of additional disk space will be used
```

Do I really need to use 619 MB of space to get this package?? Can I skip the "suggested packages" or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should install it with `apt-get`, that is the easiest and cleanest way of doing it.

The full [TexLive opus](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all), with the extra packages requires over 1 Gb of space. If you have the space my advice is to install it. Otherwise you always end up bumping into some missing LaTeX package.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing. I have a bit limited space but I guess this is one of the things to prioritize it for..